# PDF – A font displays correctly even it is not installed in PC?

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports, embedded-fonts

Is PDF store the font in binary, or which logic working behind that?

Because, I create PDF from jasper report and used font is installed in my PC only.

When i have checked generated PDF in other machine then it show the correct PDF font 
even font not installed in other PC.

Let me know if anything is missing test or verify?

Comment: Fonts used in a PDF may be fully embedded, partially embedded, or not embedded at all. Please supply the PDF in question to tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fonts can be embedded in PDF files. If one font is missing, the text is displayed anyway using another classic font. You can have a great explanation here : http://www.prepressure.com/pdf/basics/fonts

Comment: Yes, PDF embedded font not required to install. Thank you julien.